# c string manipulation for incoming strings

Tags: c, string, sockets

I am new to C and was wondering how I could do something like this:

I have a string coming in like this through a socket (it could vary)

```
"GET OK 1045 \r\nTHE RED RIDING HOOD"
```

Now I may get it in chunks of it and not completely like

```
"GET OK 10"
```

And later on

```
"45 \r\nTHE RED RIDING HOOD"
```

What is the best way to split when it finds the `\r\n` and store what came before it in a variable and what comes after it in another one.

I have tried `strtok()` but it just became way to messy and was getting errors

I tried `sscanf()` but since i may be getting chunks I can never get it to format it correctly into my variables. I am sure there my be a easy way to do this in a while loop but the splitting  is what is getting me.

```
 while((items_read = read(sock, stories_buffer, BUF_SIZE)) > 0) {
     //how do i check on stories_buffer as it comes and split it based on delimiter \r\n
 }
```

Comment: strtok is exactly the way to go. why did it got messy? I think it is best to wait for all parts, concatenate them together and go with strtok.

Comment: Did string manipulation get messy in C? Well, that's just the way it is. :)

Comment: lol thanks will go with it then (rolling eyes) :)

Comment: Some ways are better than others, but string manipulation in C will never be as smooth as in Python.

Comment: @IgalS. strtok doesn't help if you don't know how much to read. Can't just "read the entire file" with many network protocols, you will sit on read/recv forever while the other end expects a response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the socket into buffered IO and use the stdio functions like `fgets()` on it:

```
FILE *f = fdopen(sockfd, "w");
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f);
```

This should be the best option for line-based network protocols.

Comment: thank you Ctx, would this be within the while loop after reading? and also how would i still detect the `\r\n` delimiter?

Comment: Of course you can loop over the `fgets()`, which already reads only up to the next newline. You just have to strip the newline (and perhaps the carriage return) if you do not need that. You just have to make sure that the buffer is large enough; if it is not, then the message will be truncated and you have to enlarge the buffer and call `fgets()` again to read in the remaining bytes.

Comment: I see, yeah I need to store whatever is after the `\r\n` some where else for further processing and at the same time keep an eye on what i am getting for what's before the `\r\n`

Comment: @DunkRuZ As I said, `fgets()` only reads up to the next `\r\n` and stops then. A subsequent call to `fgets()` will then fetch the next line. So there will be nothing after a `\r\n`.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `"r"`?

Comment: @Gerhardh You can use "r" if you only want to read from the socket. If you also want to write with `fprintf()` or similar, you would use "w"